# How to add WMTS layer in Android Studio?

Tags: android, arcgis

I try to add WMTS layer to my map, but it show up this error:

```
E/ArcGIS.TileCache: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 19
E/ArcGIS.TileCache: at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
E/ArcGIS.TileCache: at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
E/ArcGIS.TileCache: at com.esri.android.map.ogc.WMTSLayer.getTile(SourceFile:370)
E/ArcGIS.TileCache: at com.esri.android.map.TiledServiceLayer$1.run(SourceFile:412)
```

This my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    mMapView.setEsriLogoVisible(true);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);

    WMTSLayer layer = new WMTSLayer("http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/tgos/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml");
    layer.layerInitialise();

    mMapView.addLayer(layer);
}
```

I have no idea how to solve it and how to add WMTS layer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `layer.layerInitialise()`. Just add the layer to the map and it will get initialized automatically.

I see the same behavior as you see. If I comment out `layer.layerInitialise()`, your WMTS layer displays properly on the map.